# Converting dotenv to AWS getSecretValue, how to export a module that is a mix of async and sync?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, synchronization

Apologies in advance, fairly new to Node; here's my current code which is sync:

```
const path = require('path');
const dotEnvPath = path.resolve('./.env');
require('dotenv').config({
    path: dotEnvPath
});

module.exports = {
    env: process.env,
};
```

But I want to also grab the same info from AWS secrets manager when my env is not dev, using

```
client.getSecretValue({SecretId: name})
```

which is async / callback / etc - problem is the module export finishes long before the AWS call returns resulting in an export with nothing (when not dev). I can't return a Promise because the rest of the code would have to be modified to resolve them - is there a **clean** way that I can export a module in this fashion using data from an async method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of the current state of the Javascript implementations, you can't directly export an asynchronously retrieved value because the export happens synchronously before any asynchronous operation can complete.

The usual work-around is to export a function that the caller can call and that function returns a promise that resolves with the asynchronous value.  You can then either choose to export your synchronous part directly and let the caller call your exported function to get the asynchronous part or you can just put both the synchronous and asynchronous parts in the resolved value of the promise that your function returns.  When part of an operation is synchronous and part of it is asynchronous, the whole value can only be obtained asynchronously.

> I can't return a Promise because the rest of the code would have to be modified to resolve them - is there a clean way that I can export a module in this fashion using data from an async method?

You don't have a choice here.  You can't synchronously export an asynchronous value as of the current state of Javascript.  There is a standards effort underway to provide a mechanism for asynchronous exports where the export process might actually block the loading process until the result was retrieved, but that isn't available yet.

So, if you want to incorporate an asynchronous value into your exports, the callers are going to have to change how they import if they want that asynchronously retrieved value.  There is no choice.